# Why does `read` fail saying "read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable"?

Tags: bash, read, sox

**script**

```
#!/bin/bash --

# record from microphone
rec --channels 1 /tmp/rec.sox trim 0.9 band 4k noiseprof /tmp/noiseprof &&


# convert to mp3
sox /tmp/rec.sox --compression 0.01 /tmp/rec.mp3 trim 0 -0.1 &&


# play recording to test for noise
play /tmp/rec.mp3 &&


printf "\nRemove noise? "
read reply


# If there's noise, remove it
if [[ $reply == "y" ]]; then
  sox /tmp/rec.sox --compression 0.01 /tmp/rec.mp3 trim 0 -0.1 noisered /tmp/noiseprof 0.1
  play /tmp/rec.mp3
fi
```

**Errors with**: `read error: 0: Resource temporarily unavailable`

**But**, the script works if I use the `-e` flag on `read` to enable `readline`

Comment: Does it have the same problem if the script's first line is `#!/bin/bash` without the `--` ?

Comment: This is old, but may still be relevant? [\[solved\] sox causes "Resource temporarily unavailable"](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=279795)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens is that one of your SoX programs (`sox`, `play`, `rec`) has changed how `stdin` is behaving, making it non-blocking. Typically, something is calling [`fcntl`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fcntl.2.html)`(0, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)`.

When a call to the [`read()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html) system call is made on a non-blocking file descriptor, the call does not wait: either there is already something to read in the kernel buffer and it is returned, or `read()` fails and `errno` is set to `EAGAIN`.

When Bash meets this `EAGAIN` error while reading from stdin with the `read` command, it displays the "Resource temporarily unavailable" message you have met.

Try adding `<&-` at the end of each of your SoX commands; this will close `stdin` for them and they won't be able to alter how it is working.

Comment: Yes, thanks, this worked. Another solution (from IRC) is to add `</dev/null` to the `play` command.

Comment: @PoundHash You can redirect from any file as long as this is not `/dev/stdin` but not opening a file at all (with `<&-`) is always better (resource efficiency) as long as it does not make your (ill-written) app crash.